# Validation trigger not working in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I am working on a trigger for a class project.

I have a table named `salesman` with a column named `type`. All employees in the table currently have a `type` of `full`, `part` or `temp`.

The purpose of the trigger is to check a newly inserted row's `type` and make sure that it matches one of the three that already exist. If it does it should allow the insert, if not it should stop it or roll it back. Thank you for any ideas that you may have!

This is the latest permutation of the code.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_validate_emp_type
ON salesman
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @job varchar (20)

    SELECT @job = (SELECT type FROM inserted)

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM salesman WHERE UPPER(type) = UPPER(@job))      
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        PRINT 'employee type not valid'
    END
END
```

Comment: You *assume* that an `INSERT` only contains one row; this is simply not true. An `INSERT` can contain 0+ rows. See [The Silent Bug I Find in Most Triggers](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/)

Comment: You should not even consider a trigger here, this is why *check constraints* exist.

Comment: You say "make sure that it matches one of the three that already exist" where are these 3 types coming from?

Comment: This is an AFTER trigger.  So the row has _already_ been inserted, so it will always be "valid".

Comment: Do not use PRINT in a trigger of a production system for many reasons. To indicate an error occurred, you `THROW` one with the appropriate information (ignoring the fact that a constraint would be preferred in this situation).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, since this is for a class I'm stuck with a trigger. I know it isn't the best solution, but it's an academic exercise. To answer Dale K's question, the 3 types are coming from the table. They have already been entered as types for previous entries.

Comment: It's wrong even as an academic exercise. Perhaps you should write it, then add an explanation why you think it's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As several people pointed out, this looks like a job for a check constraint or a foreign key.

eg

```
create table salesman(id int primary key, type varchar(20) check (type in ('a','b')))
```

or

```
create table salesman_type (type varchar(20) primary key )
create table salesman(id int primary key, type varchar(20) references salesman_type)
```

But if you really did want to write a trigger that prevented the insertion of values that didn't already exist in the table, you could do it like this:

```
    use tempdb
    go
    create table salesman
    (
      id int identity primary key, 
      type varchar(20) not null, 
      index ix_salesman_type(type) 
    )
    insert into salesman(id,type) values (1,'a')
    insert into salesman(id,type) values (2,'b')
    go
    CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER trg_validate_emp_type
    ON salesman
    FOR INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN
    
        IF EXISTS 
        (
          SELECT * 
          FROM inserted 
          WHERE type not in
              (
                select type 
                from salesman
                where id not in (select id from inserted)
              )
        )
        BEGIN
           throw 50001, 'employee type not valid', 1;
        END
    END

go

insert into salesman(id,type) values (3,'c') -- fails

insert into salesman(id,type) values (3,'a') -- succeeds
```

Since XACT_ABORT defaults to ON in a trigger, you can simply THROW instead of ROLLBACK + PRINT, and the client gets a better error message.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. Since I know that in the real world this is not the best way to do this, would you mind explaining the second line of the second table creation code? We haven't seen the "references" statement before.

Comment: It's a shortcut for declaring a Foreign Key constraint.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the value of a column there are more efficent ways.
Best practice is to define constraints.
When the value are stored in a table then use FOREIGN KEY constraint; in other case use CHECK constraint.

Comment: To be a good answer you need to provide the code to create a check constraint that meets the OPs needs.